# AWS policy that limit the IAM user to send SES emails from a specific sender

Tags: amazon-web-services, policy, amazon-ses, amazon-iam

It is possible to use IAM credentials to allow to send mails from specific sender?

I mean, for example, I have two different domains and senders configurated into SES: info@example1.com and info@example2.com. Is there any way to limit a IAM user and its credentials to just send mails from info@example1.com?

I tried to specify a condition in a IAM policy defined into to the user permissions. However I could not find a condition that can solve my problem.

Also I tried to solve the issue using STMP credentials, but I have the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the policy you tried?

Comment: This is the SES normal policy. I could not define any conditions because they are not applicable to my problem.
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ses:SendEmail",
        "ses:SendRawEmail"
      ],
      "Sid": "Stmt1370533724000",
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is possible to use IAM credentials to allow to send mails from
>   specific sender?

***NO***

See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/control-user-access.html

> ***You can't specify a particular Amazon SES resource in an IAM policy.
>   You only control access to Amazon SES actions.*** Therefore, Amazon SES
>   does not use Amazon Resource Names (ARNs), which identify resources in
>   a policy. When you write a policy to control access to Amazon SES
>   actions, you use * as the resource.

(emphasis mine)

You can control what API calls IAM accounts can make(like ses:SendEmail), but you can not restrict what parameters they can use with those API calls(like the source email address)

Comment: You can though specify configuration-set when using `ses:SendEmail*` and particular configuration-set can be linked with a verified identity (a.k.a. sender) right?

Comment: This answer was from 2013, things have changed since then. as you point out.

Answer (score 27):

This may have changed since the original answer. You can now do something like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
     {
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": ["ses:SendEmail"],
       "Resource":"*",
           "Condition": {
             "StringEquals": {
               "ses:FromAddress": "here@somewhere.com"
             }
         }
       }
    ] 
}
```

The AWS docs now reflect this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/control-user-access.html